# Link between multi language builds

Tags: angular, internationalization

I set up a Angular website to work with their i18n implementation, what results in two builds that work fine separately:

- `/dist/pt/`
- `/dist/en/`

Now I'm trying to create the switch language feature, I was hoping that would be possible only using a simple anchor link (`<a>`), but I had tested a lot of solutions and ended up appending the new language after the current one (`/pt/en`) or ending up redirecting to the correct URL (`/en`), but in the scope of the current build the URL doesn't exist, so it goes to the 404 page.

Is there any solution that doesn't required creating a function for that?

---

I tested and didn't work:

- `<a href="/en">`
- `<a href="./en">`
- `<a href="../en">`
- `<a routerLink="/en">`
- `<a routerLink="./en">`
- `<a routerLink="../en">`
- `<a [href]="prop"> // prop = "/en"`

---

Preview: https://deploy-preview-165--querido-diario-plataforma.netlify.app/

Code: https://github.com/lguima/querido-diario-frontend/blob/i18n-poc/src/app/modules/components/header/header.component.html#L22

Comment: Did you test with `ng serve` or by deploying the build to a server? AFAIK `ng serve` only builds one language. If you deploy to a server, you also need to correctly [configure the server](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-common-deploy#configure-a-server).

Comment: Hi! I deployed to a server, specifically Netlify, with the following redirect rules:
- https://github.com/lguima/querido-diario-frontend/blob/i18n-poc/netlify.toml